# Crash log meaning -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, crash

I received 30+ crashreports from only one user. Nobody is showing the same behavior. Normally I could find out what the problem is since theres always some reference to my code but this one hasn't.

They all are from type:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

And they all start with this (which i think is the problem:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18c3c2f50 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x198da01fc objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18c3c2e90 +[NSException raise:format:] + 128
3   CoreFoundation                  0x18c2e2bbc -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:] + 144
...
```

Does anybody know what those last two lines mean in my crashlog?

Oh and again this app is old and pre ARC.

UPDATE #2

So i managed to get the credentials of the users accounts and after logging in the app crashes directly on this line:

```
[[UILabel new] autorelease];
```

with a

```
Thread 26: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x0)
```

UPDATE #2

After a restart the app just went to my tableview without any problems.

Comment: Is that really all you are doing on that line?

Comment: Yes. After initial download has completed a tableview is shown. This line o fcode is in the init of the tableview headers custom class

Comment: Do you think this can be solved by using ARC?

Comment: as I said in my reply below: the line has no real side effects. You simply create a UILabel and let it disappear. You can simply remove this line.

Comment: I don't believe that ARC has much to do with it.

Comment: Yes I know but I just pointed out where Xcode pointed me when the crash occured (exception breakpoint). After building again this specific crash was gone but appearently the user still has problem. The crashlogs all show the same thing which I think is a memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does is include the exception name or some portion of the log? Most likely you are trying to get a substring that is longer than the string. You might need to check the length of the string when computing the range.

If you are not even assigning the UILabel to a variable or anything, why are you creating it? This line does nothing other than creating an unused UILabel.

Maybe UILabel does not behave well if you are creating ephemeral instances.

If the line is indeed only `[[UILabel new] autorelease];` you can and should remove it.

Comment: No exception name so far I can see. Did however managed to reproduce a crash after loggin in with his account.